# Trouble getting Reg Ex to check for string of any length that has alphabets and/or spaces

Tags: python-2.7

have the following while loop:

```
word = raw_input("Enter secret string:")
  while word not in (" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
    print "Please guess only letters and spaces"
    word = raw_input("Enter secret string:")
```

And my goal is for have python to prompt the user for a string that only contains words and spaces. I've tried the following code:

```
import re 
word = raw_input("Enter secret string:") 
while not (re.match("[a-zA-Z ]$", word) or re.match("[a-zA-Z]$", word)):     

  print "Please enter only letters and spaces" word = raw_input("Enter secret string:")
```

But this seems to restrict my guess to being at least 3 characters long. I'd like the input to be any length. Help would really be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` condition checks for opposite conditions, so it will always be `True`. Also, your regex looks for the first letter starting from the end because you're using `$`.  Personally I would just check for illegal characters, instead of using regex.

```
legal_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
legal_chars += legal_chars.upper() + " "

def contains_illegal_chars(word):
    for char in word:
        if char not in legal_chars:
            return True
    return False
```

and then change the `while` statement to
`while not contains_illegal_chars(word):`...

**Side Note**

https://regex101.com/#python is a great resource for testing out regular expressions